# Leave from a repository in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I was invited to a project on Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online) and I accepted. But now, I want to leave the project and I can't find the option to do that.

Since I'm not an administrator, I can't just delete the project/account, and the owner is no longer active so he can't remove me. The project is now linked to my account and **I just want to leave**.

[image]

Comment: What's the detail mean of no longer active of the account owner?

Answer (score 0):

Usually [delete users from the owner's Visual Studio Team Services account](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/add-account-users-assign-access-levels-team-services#delete-users-from-your-visual-studio-team-services-account) is the simplest solution in your scenario.

Since the owner is no longer active, you or others in thie project team could try to change the account ower. If no one have enough permission, you may have to contact ***Team service support***.

> You must have at least **Basic** access, not Stakeholder, and T**eam
>   Services project collection administrator or account owner
>   permissions**. If no one has these permissions, contact [Team Services
>   Support](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/support).
>
> Source Link: [Change account owner for Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/zh-cn/docs/setup-admin/team-services/change-account-ownership-vs)

[image]

Comment: The Team Services Support team were super helpful when I reached out to them (for a different matter). Since you don't own the projects and aren't trying to delete anything or gain special privileges, I'm sure they'll have problem removing you from those projects.

Comment: Well, it doesn't make sense. If the  the project owner is no longer active any more. And no one including the VSTS support team can help to remove from those projects.  Does you have to live with the abandoned project forever? If so, you may have to ignore the projects or waiting an upgrade to fix this problem.

Comment: OMG typo!! "I'm sure they'll have NO problem with removing you..."

Comment: Glad you have figured out the issue and thanks for the sharing.  
 If it helped, could you mark it as an answer.